# Don't understand why I am receiving SIGKILL on python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to python and I'm trying to make a code on a code challenge website that when given a list of integers, returns the integer closest to zero. If there are two different integers with the same difference, e.g. 3 and -3, should return None. (However if the number is repeated, e.g. 3 and 3, then it doesn't count as that)

I've made a code that seems to work on outside python interpeters, but inside the website it gives an error of "Process exited prematurely with a SIGKILL signal."

On an external Python interpreter this seems to return the integer I'm looking for

```
def closest(lst):

    ans = list(filter(lambda x: abs(0-x) == min([abs(0-i) for i in set(lst)]), set(lst)))

    return ans[0] if len(ans) < 2 else None
```

Is there something in my code causing inefficiency or is it the website?

Comment: SIGKILL sounds like your program is getting killed because it's too slow.

Comment: You're recomputing `set(lst)` for every element of `set(lst)`.

Comment: Also, `abs(0-x)` is just `abs(x)`, but that's minor compared to recomputing `set(lst)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the coding website is testing your function by passing a very large generator for `lst`. When your program converts it to a `set`, it loads the entirety of the input into memory. If this uses too much memory, your process may be killed by the OOM killer.

I think the following solution ought to work. Note that it just iterates over `lst` and doesn't construct any other large data structures; the only state is the stack variables `c` and `ans`. Therefore it uses a *constant* amount of memory.

```
def closest(lst):
    (c, ans) = (None, None)
    for i in lst:
        if (c is None) or (abs(i) < abs(c)):
            (c, ans) = (i, i)
        elif i == -1 * c:
            ans = None
    return ans
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that the problem was set(lst)... I added this in to get around the problem of repeated numbers causing the code to return "None"

What is involved in rewriting the problem using constant memory? Sorry, I'm not familiar with the term yet

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand. Though I do just want to clear up one thing. Does the constant "c" have to be added? Would just the following work?

def closest(lst):
    ans = None
    for i in lst:
        if (ans is None) or (abs(i) < abs(ans)):
            ans = i
            print ans
        elif i == -1 * ans:
            ans = None
    return ans

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to edit that so that the code is readable. :/ Basically I mean replacing the (c, ans) = (None, None) with ans = None and then all subsequent instances of "c" with ans

Comment: 1) `c` is not a constant. 2) No, that doesn't work; try running your code on the input `[5, -5, 7]`. If I understand you correctly, it should return `None`, but your code would return `7`.